# creationExtras.get(APPLICATION_KEY) always returns null

Tags: android, mvvm, fragment, viewmodel

I'm trying to make viewModel with dependencies and Application app = (Application) creationExtras.get(APPLICATION_KEY); always null,
That means i can't to get any dependencies, like Context or my DBHealper instance.

```
public class MainFragmentVM extends ViewModel {

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public MainFragmentVM(@NonNull Application app) {
    }

    public static final ViewModelInitializer<MainFragmentVM> initializer = new ViewModelInitializer<>(
            MainFragmentVM.class,
            creationExtras -> {
                Application app = (Application) creationExtras.get(APPLICATION_KEY);
                assert app != null;
                return new MainFragmentVM(app);
            }
    );
}
```

Here is my Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainFragmentLayoutBinding binding;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = MainFragmentLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MainFragmentVM myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
                ViewModelProvider.Factory.from(MainFragmentVM.initializer)
        ).get(MainFragmentVM.class);
    }
}
```

and here is MyApp:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(DataBase.getInstance(this).getReadableDatabase());
    }

    public DBHelper getDbHelper() {
        return dbHelper;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using? Please include your `dependencies` block.